# Github CoPilot problem with error statusCode=407

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, github-copilot

I'm working for a company using proxy and that setting is done, to be able to use CoPilot.

Afterwards I started getting this error, CoPilot seems to work but the error keeps coming.

Anyone have the same problem? Or the solution?

`[ERROR] [default] [2023-01-23T09:22:29.101Z] Request Error: tunneling socket could not be established, statusCode=407`

`[ERROR] [ghostText] [2023-01-23T09:22:29.102Z] Error on ghost text request FetchError: tunneling socket could not be established, statusCode=407`

Tried to update the proxy and restart, have installed a extension to help to make all certificates in **Keychain Access** available.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your proxy needs autentification. Status code 407:

> 407 Proxy Authentication Required

Try this:

```
"http.proxy": "http://YourProxyIP:ProxyPort/"
"http.proxyAuthorization": "Authorization: Basic RE9NQUlOXHVzZXI6cGFzcw=="
```

Authorization basic is base64 encoded **DOMAIN\user:pass**

If you dont use SSL, you have to use this option:

```
"http.proxyStrictSSL": false
```

because you will get this error:

> Request Error: unable to get local issuer certificate

Also if you store you credentials to settings.json, keep in mind to protect this file with ACL.

PowerShell script to remove the local admin group for example:

*PowerShell 5.1 min version required for the code below:*

```
$settings = "$env:appdata\Code\$env:username\settings.json"
$acl = (Get-Item $settings).GetAccessControl('Access')
$acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($true,$true) # removes the ACL inheritance
$accesToRemove = $acl.Access | ?{ $_.IsInherited -eq $false -and $_.IdentityReference -eq 'BUILTIN\Administrators' }
$acl.RemoveAccessRule($accesToRemove)
Set-Acl -AclObject $acl $settings
```

Comment: Could you please detail some context? What OS this is for, and where to try this code?

Comment: As you can see the usage is in powershell, but same is for any other platform, you need to edit visual studio code settings.json